# Opengl bad filter?

Tags: c, opengl, glsl

I am currently trying to implement deferred shading in C and Opengl 3 on the linux operating system. I cant figure out whats causing this rendering problem:
[image: image of a red 3D tank shape with with 'glitchy' looking grey, dashed lines running across it. The image has a black background and the tank shape is sitting on a blue field.]

I have a fbo with the following textures: diffuse, normal, depth, light. The first three are self explanatory, and the light texture is where the lights get blended with each other. Then this light texture is combined with the diffuse texture onto the default framebuffer.

I suspect that this is a filtering problem, so this is my light texture's attachment setup:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo->textures[FBO_LIGHT_TEXTURE]);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Is this actually a filtering problem or could it be something else?

Comment: Doesn't look like any filtering problem I've ever seen. This resembles issues you sometimes see when you're drawing into the same buffer as you're sampling.

Comment: Oh ok thank you, Il try it out

Comment: Try what out? I'm not really clear what the problem here is, I'm just telling you what it looks like to me ;) Those artifacts are usually caused by doing something with memory you shouldn't have (e.g. reading and writing at the same time). You'd need to include more code, like the FBO setup to really diagnose this.

Comment: I meant Il check it out lol :). I am doing some reading/writing at the same time lol. I think you are right :)

Comment: I fixed the read/write issue, but the problem is still the same, thanks a mil though :). Disabling face culling seems to reduce the problem for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Wow this was a really weird bug. This was caused by my depth buffer. Basically, my light sources were somehow messing up my depth buffer. I fixed this by using glDepthMask(GL_FALSE); before rendering the lights and glDepthMask(GL_TRUE); after I was done.